# How to install IBM DB2 Database Driver on Ubuntu for Node.js

Tags: drivers, database, node.js, db2

I need assistance installing IBM DB2 drivers onto Ubuntu.

Using Ubuntu 14.04, I'm attempting to create a simple web page that gets served by the [node.js](http://www.nodejs.org/) server-side framework. A server-side-javascript will be making a simple query to an IBM db2 9.5 database located on a windows server (within the same LAN as the Ubuntu machine).

I got [node.js](http://www.nodejs.org/) installed on Ubuntu 14.04 using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs nodejs-legacy npm
```

Then, unnecessarily, I added ODBC support with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install git unixodbc unixodbc-dev ; git clone git://github.com/wankdanker/node-odbc.git ; cd node-odbc ; node-gyp configure build ; npm install odbc
```

After this, I discovered there was a [npm](https://www.npmjs.org/package/ibm_db) for getting IBM DB2 accessible from node.js

A prerequisite, though, is that I must first download and install the IBM DB2 driver onto Ubuntu.

From the [IBM website](http://www.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/), I downloaded a file named:

```
v9.5fp10_linuxx64_dsdriver.tar.gz
```

I found [these instructions](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.install.doc/doc/t0054799.html) for installing the IBM DB2 driver.

The instructions state:

> On Linux and UNIX operating systems, IBM Data Server Driver Package is
>   installed by running the **[installDSDriver](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0056288.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.1.0%2F3-6-2-6-137)** command.

However, the v9.5fp10_linuxx64_dsdriver.tar.gz file-archive doesn't contain any command called **installDSDriver** and Ubuntu doesn't natively know this command.

Where and how can I execute this **installDSDriver** command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Data Server Driver package for DB2 9.5 does not include the install script - that was introduced in 9.7. Installation in 9.5 is manual.

The installDSDriver script does a couple of things - it unzips the driver files to several sub-directories, and it creates a db2profile file for bash users.

You have several options:

- Download the 9.7 DSDriver package and continue following your documentation. You will be able to connect to a 9.5 database with this driver without issue.
- If you wish to use the 9.5 driver, you could download the ODBC and
  CLI only driver, since you do not need the Ruby, PHP, etc:

  http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24025865

  The installation and configuration instructions are here:

  http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSEPGG_9.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.cli.doc/doc/t0023864.html
- An alternative option is to use node-ibm_db to connect instead of
  ODBC. This way you will not require the use of an ODBC driver
  manager. This package will also download the required driver
  automatically. This would be my recommended option.

  https://github.com/ibmdb/node-ibm_db/